# BlobNotFound Error - While opening WebView deployed on OpenVSCode-server in Chrome browser

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

We have developed WebViews which are bundled & deployed as custom extension on [openvscode server - version v1.67.2  - https://github.com/gitpod-io/openvscode-server] setup locally on Ubuntu 18.04.

I understand that WebView contents are loaded in isolated context and to achieve this, following construct is used...
"webviewContentExternalBaseUrlTemplate": "https://{{uuid}}.vscode-cdn.net/insider/181b43c0e2949e36ecb623d8cc6de29d4fa2bae8/out/vs/workbench/contrib/webview/browser/pre/",

While URL pattern like those above were returning HTTP 200,till couple of days back.
Today I am getting HTTP 404 error with following message.

*BlobNotFoundThe specified blob does not exist. RequestId:4a1fd970-801e-00dd-7b6b-f7b7a6000000 Time:2022-11-13T14:20:19.6557972Z*
[BlobNotFound Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVNlr.png)
and this stops further loading of the WebView, even the workbench loading shows similar message.

Tried directly accessing the generated URLs, same error.

https://1a65bdna6qkjoq12kusrstigt7drpf2luc77qqb5qaoigacij400.vscode-cdn.net/insider/181b43c0e2949e36ecb623d8cc6de29d4fa2bae8/out/vs/workbench/contrib/webview/browser/pre/index.html?id=307bf716-be90-47ad-a180-2d9e07a992e5&swVersion=4&extensionId=&platform=browser&vscode-resource-base-authority=vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net&parentOrigin=http://localhost:3000&remoteAuthority=localhost:3000

Please let me know if anyone has faced similar issue.

Thank you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Openvscode server:1.65.0 has the same error.
When i upgrade to version 1.73.0 , it fixed.

Comment: Thank you !! Upgrading to 1.73.1 solved the error.